# Runnable Jar cannot find class when i try to run in my server

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jar

Heres my problem. I am trying to run the following application on a server: https://github.com/googleads/aw-reporting, i followed the readme, imported the project into my Eclipse and made one Runnable Jar with the option that also creates a lib folder with all the Jars inside. Now when i run the jar in my machine everything works fine, but i uploaded both the jar and the lib folder to my server(both machines run on linux) and i keep getting this error:

```
2014-04-11 04:21:45,467 [ERROR|com.google.api.ads.adwords.jaxws.extensions.AwReporting|AwReporting] Unexpected error accessing the API: Error creating bean with name 'sqlAuthTokenPersister' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/rst_ericg/aw-reporting/aw-report.jar!/com/google/api/ads/adwords/jaxws/extensions/report/model/persistence/sql/SqlAuthTokenPersister.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: : Cannot find class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean] for bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [aw-report-sql-beans.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean] for bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [aw-report-sql-beans.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlAuthTokenPersister' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/rst_ericg/aw-reporting/aw-report.jar!/com/google/api/ads/adwords/jaxws/extensions/report/model/persistence/sql/SqlAuthTokenPersister.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: : Cannot find class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean] for bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [aw-report-sql-beans.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean] for bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [aw-report-sql-beans.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:730)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1051)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:955)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:490)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.google.api.ads.adwords.jaxws.extensions.AwReporting.initApplicationContextAndProperties(AwReporting.java:438)
    at com.google.api.ads.adwords.jaxws.extensions.AwReporting.main(AwReporting.java:126)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean] for bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [aw-report-sql-beans.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1269)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:356)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:895)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:853)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:768)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:795)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:723)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:276)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:260)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:416)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1261)
    ... 26 more
```

I double checked the lib folder, the jar that contains the `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean` is there, but somehow he cant find it, its the exact same folder that works fine on my computer.

> Manifest-Version: 1.0
>   Class-Path: . aw-report_lib/javax.inject-1.jar aw-report_lib/jdo2-api-
>    2.3-eb.jar aw-report_lib/transaction-api-1.1.jar aw-report_lib/servle
>    t-api-2.5.jar aw-report_lib/spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar aw-report_
>    lib/spring-core-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar aw-report_lib/commons-logging-1.1.1
>    .jar aw-report_lib/spring-context-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar aw-report_lib/spr
>    ing-aop-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar aw-report_lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar aw-report
>    _lib/spring-expression-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar aw-report_lib/spring-tx-3.2.
>    2.RELEASE.jar aw-report_lib/spring-orm-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar aw-report_li
>    b/spring-jdbc-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar aw-report_lib/hibernate-core-4.2.1.Fi
>    nal.jar aw-report_lib/antlr-2.7.7.jar aw-report_lib/jboss-logging-3.1
>    .0.GA.jar aw-report_lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar aw-report_lib/jboss-transacti
>    on-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar aw-report_lib/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1
>    .0.1.Final.jar aw-report_lib/javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar aw-report_lib/hi
>    bernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar aw-report_lib/joda-time-2
>    .2.jar aw-report_lib/opencsv-2.3.jar aw-report_lib/gson-2.2.4.jar aw-
>    report_lib/guava-jdk5-16.0-rc1.jar aw-report_lib/ads-lib-1.26.0.jar a
>    w-report_lib/guice-3.0.jar aw-report_lib/guice-assistedinject-3.0.jar
>     aw-report_lib/guice-multibindings-3.0.jar aw-report_lib/commons-conf
>    iguration-1.7.jar aw-report_lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar aw-repo
>    rt_lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar aw-report_lib/commons-digester-1.8.1.jar 
>    aw-report_lib/commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar aw-report_lib/slf4j-api-1.6
>    .1.jar aw-report_lib/google-api-client-1.17.0-rc.jar aw-report_lib/go
>    ogle-oauth-client-1.17.0-rc.jar aw-report_lib/google-http-client-1.17
>    .0-rc.jar aw-report_lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar aw-report_lib/httpclient-4.0
>    .1.jar aw-report_lib/httpcore-4.0.1.jar aw-report_lib/commons-codec-1
>    .3.jar aw-report_lib/google-http-client-jackson2-1.17.0-rc.jar aw-rep
>    ort_lib/jackson-core-2.1.3.jar aw-report_lib/junit-4.10.jar aw-report
>    _lib/hamcrest-core-1.1.jar aw-report_lib/spring-test-3.2.2.RELEASE.ja
>    r aw-report_lib/h2-1.3.172.jar aw-report_lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1
>    .6.jar aw-report_lib/jtds-1.3.0.jar aw-report_lib/mongo-java-driver-2
>    .11.0.jar aw-report_lib/objectify-4.0.jar aw-report_lib/guava-14.0.1.
>    jar aw-report_lib/guava-16.0-rc1.jar aw-report_lib/adwords-appengine-
>    1.26.0.jar aw-report_lib/ads-lib-appengine-1.26.0.jar aw-report_lib/g
>    oogle-api-client-appengine-1.17.0-rc.jar aw-report_lib/google-oauth-c
>    lient-appengine-1.17.0-rc.jar aw-report_lib/google-http-client-appeng
>    ine-1.17.0-rc.jar aw-report_lib/google-oauth-client-servlet-1.17.0-rc
>    .jar aw-report_lib/google-http-client-jdo-1.17.0-rc.jar aw-report_lib
>    /google-api-client-servlet-1.17.0-rc.jar aw-report_lib/log4j-1.2.17.j
>    ar aw-report_lib/jmustache-1.8.jar aw-report_lib/core-renderer-R8.jar
>     aw-report_lib/itext-2.0.8.jar aw-report_lib/bcmail-jdk14-138.jar aw-
>    report_lib/bcprov-jdk14-138.jar aw-report_lib/commons-io-1.3.2.jar aw
>    -report_lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar aw-report_lib/mockito-all-1.8.5.jar a
>    w-report_lib/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev113-1.17.0-rc.jar
>   Main-Class: com.google.api.ads.adwords.jaxws.extensions.AwReporting

Comment: What is your working directory? The path to `lib` might be relative to that.

Comment: The jar and the lib are both on the same folder, i run the jar with java -Xmx1G -jar aw-report.jar

Comment: Could you post the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file?

Comment: updated with the manifest file

Answer (score 0):

Just as an alternative to your method, which might also solve your problem, I suggest you add a Maven plugin (if you are using Maven) that automatically packages your app and all its dependencies inside a single executable jar file.

Just add the Maven Assembly plugin to your plugin list and run ***mvn package*** goal. That's it, you get the fully-packged executable jar + your original jar without the dependencies.

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <mainClass>com.mypackage.RunApp</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```